# iptables mport module not found

Tags: iptables, debian-wheezy

I'm replacing a wireless router/firewall running Tomato with a Debian server, and I was excited to have found tomato's iptables config so I could [directly import it to the new server](https://serverfault.com/questions/566682/copying-iptables-config-from-tomato-to-ubuntu-server) (my question before this). The iptables config file (at bottom) from Tomato fails <kbd>iptables-restore</kbd> in Debian:

```
# iptables-restore < iptables.eth0-eth1
iptables-restore v1.4.14: Couldn't load match `mport':No such file or directory

Error occurred at line: 7
Try `iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.
```

**Is there a way to get mport into "modern" iptables?**
<sub>Or could you please help me translate `mport` to `multiport`?</sub>

Googling for `iptables mport` was pretty rough, but I eventually found [someone complaining mport is gone](https://dev.openwrt.org/ticket/398) and a [multiport tutorial](http://howtonixnux.blogspot.com/2008/03/iptables-using-multiport.html) with passing reference to the mport extension, which led to me snooping around the two box's filesystems for modules and also trying every "firewall" tool Debian has, wishing for one to magically come with `mport`. I admit to being quite spoiled by Tomato's user interface -- every Debian package I have tried since has left me more and more confused (gui or cli). If I could get the server to briefly route everything, I think `mason` might work. No wonder everyone hates iptables.

I spent more time trying to figure out the errors than I should. Had I spent that much time trying to understand `iptables`, I probably could have translated the `mport` rules to `multiport`. Also, I pondered posting to SuperUser, however, the few iptables tagged questions weren't in the same league as ones I'm reading here in ServerFault.

---

**Looking for modules:**
I ssh'd into the wireless router with `tomato` firmware, I found the module <kbd>libipt_mport.so</kbd> in `/usr/lib/iptables`. But in the `/lib/modules/2.4.20/kernel/net/ipv4/netfilter` directory, there is no <kbd>libipt_mport.so</kbd>, only `ipt_multiport.o`.

On the Debian box (fresh install of wheezy), I used `updatedb` and `locate` to search on `MASQ` (for MASQUERADE object) and found the directory
`/lib/modules/3.2.0-4-amd64/kernel/net/ipv4/netfilter` has a good array of `iptable_*` and `nf_nat_*` `ko` files. The search also found `libxt_multiport.so` in `/lib/xtables`, but there is no reference to object modules for `mport`.

Additionally, are there any other problems below? I see the layer 7 stuff and have a feeling this will make for more complications next.

---

**Tomato's config file:**
Notes:
» 99.1.81.209 is WAN ip
» 10.0.0.2 is ip for this Debian firewall
» 10.0.0.20 is a server
» tomato's public interface `vlan0` changed to `eth0`
» tomato's internal interface `br0` changed to `eth1`
» ports 5060:5090 are for VoIP (probably don't need that whole range?)

```
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:QOSO - [0:0]
-A QOSO -j CONNMARK --restore-mark --mask 0xff
-A QOSO -m connmark ! --mark 0/0xff00 -j RETURN
-A QOSO -p tcp -m mport --dports 80,443   -m bcount --range 0x0-0x7ffff -j CONNMARK --set-return 0x2/0xFF
-A QOSO -p tcp -m mport --dports 80,443   -m bcount --range 0x80000 -j CONNMARK --set-return 0x4/0xFF
-A QOSO -p udp --dport 53   -m bcount --range 0x0-0x7ff -j CONNMARK --set-return 0x1/0xFF
-A QOSO -p tcp --dport 53   -m bcount --range 0x0-0x7ff -j CONNMARK --set-return 0x1/0xFF
-A QOSO -p udp --dport 53   -m bcount --range 0x800 -j CONNMARK --set-return 0x5/0xFF
-A QOSO -p tcp --dport 53   -m bcount --range 0x800 -j CONNMARK --set-return 0x5/0xFF
-A QOSO -p udp --dport 1024:65535   -j CONNMARK --set-return 0x5/0xFF
-A QOSO -p tcp --dport 1024:65535   -j CONNMARK --set-return 0x5/0xFF
-A QOSO -p udp -m mport --ports 5060:5090  -m layer7 --l7dir /etc/l7-protocols --l7proto sip -j CONNMARK --set-return 0x101/0xFF
-I QOSO -j BCOUNT
-A QOSO -j CONNMARK --set-return 0x4
-A FORWARD -o eth0 -j QOSO
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -j QOSO
COMMIT
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -d 10.0.0.2/255.255.255.0 -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -p icmp -d 99.1.81.209 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.2
-A PREROUTING  -p tcp -m tcp -d 99.1.81.209 --dport 22 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.2:22
-A PREROUTING -p tcp  -d 99.1.81.209 --dport 10022 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.20:22
-A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dport 22 -s 10.0.0.2/255.255.255.0 -d 10.0.0.20 -j SNAT --to-source 99.1.81.209
:upnp - [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -d 99.1.81.209 -j upnp
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -i eth1 -d 99.1.81.209 -j DROP
-A INPUT -m state --state INVALID -j DROP
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-N shlimit
-A shlimit -m recent --set --name shlimit
-A shlimit -m recent --update --hitcount 3 --seconds 60 --name shlimit -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -j shlimit
-A INPUT -i eth1 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp  -m tcp -d 10.0.0.2 --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
-A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth1 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m state --state INVALID -j DROP
-A FORWARD -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -m tcpmss --mss 1461: -j TCPMSS --set-mss 1460
:L7in - [0:0]
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -j L7in
-A L7in -m layer7 --l7dir /etc/l7-protocols --l7proto sip -j RETURN
:wanin - [0:0]
:wanout - [0:0]
-A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -j wanin
-A FORWARD -o eth0 -j wanout
-A FORWARD -i eth1 -j ACCEPT
:upnp - [0:0]
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -j upnp
-A wanin  -p tcp -m tcp -d 10.0.0.20 --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and on my system I have `multiport` and not `mport`. You can see `man iptables` if you are unsure.

Comment: Yes, your ubuntu is just like my debian and yes, my `man` doesn't know about mport.

Comment: What have you tried? It's pretty trivial to write a multiport rule, and the man page is crystal clear on how it works.

Comment: Hi Michael, everything *but* learning iptables themselves. That's today's goal. Get a good base config set up, then go back and investigate the config I fetched. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, the parameters for the `multiport` module is identical to the parameters for the `mport` module you've shown.

Try a simple search-and-replace:

```
s/-m mport/-m multiport/g
```

PS: Certainly not *everyone* hates iptables; I personally *LOVE* iptables ;-)

Comment: But does multiport accept ranges?

Comment: @danmaz74 try `man iptables` and search for `multiport`. Short answer, just in case you don't have access to a linux console: YES.

Comment: Yes thanks actually I had found it it works fine :)